# No viable conversion from 'Template<int>::Memberclass' to 'const int'

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having a problem with return value/reference. I'm writing a template (queue), and `Front()` function is supposed to return the element from the front of the queue, but I get an error -- `No viable conversion from 'Queue<int>::Node' to 'const int'`. When I remove `const`, I get `Non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'Queue<int>::Node'` instead, and other variations of reference/no reference, const/no const give me either of the two errors. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &, const Queue<T> & );
private:
    class Node
    {
        friend class Queue<T>;
    public:
        Node(const T &t): node(t) {next = 0;}
    private:
        T front;
        T back;
        T node;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *front;
    Node *back;
public:
    Queue() : front(0), back(0) {}
    ~Queue();
    bool Empty()
    {
        return front == 0;
    }
    T& Front()
    {
        if (Empty())
            cout << "Очередь пуста." << endl;
        else
        {
            T const & temp = *front; // error here
            return temp;
        }
    }
    /* ... */
};

template <class T> ostream& operator<< (ostream &, const Queue<T> & );

int main()
{
    Queue<int> *queueInt = new Queue<int>;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        queueInt->Push(i);
        cout << "Pushed " << i << endl;
    }
    if (!queueInt->Empty())
    {
        queueInt->Pop();
        cout << "Pop" << endl;
    }
    queueInt->Front();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to return _something_ if someone calls `Front` on an empty queue (or throw an exception). Otherwise you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mat Thanks for pointing it out! I completely forgot about returning.

Comment: Your compiler can point it out too (enable warnings) - though this one sometimes requires turning on optimizations too (needs flow analysis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Node` class definition doesn't make much sense: the way it's now, each node stores 3 data values: `front`, `back` and `node`. Is the class supposed to be a queue of triples?

Nevertheless, in your `Front()` function, you to need to return the "payload" of the front node (i.e. return something of type `T`), not the node itself. Something like this:

```
T& Front()
{
    if (Empty())
        cout << "Очередь пуста." << endl;
    else
    {
        return front->node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works with this. As for `Node` class, `front` and `back` are supposed to be pointers to the first and the last elements of the queue, but I guess I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: @Kaworu You alread have `front` and `back` as pointers to `Node` inside `Queue`, and that's OK. Why would you need any reference to `front` and `back` inside each node?

Comment: I don't. Now I'm trying to figure out why I put them there in the first place ) Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
T const & temp = *front;
```

with

```
T& temp = front->front;
```

`Queue<T>::front` is a pointer to a `Node`, in other words, `*front` is a `Node`. You are trying then to assign a `Node` to a `T& const` and, since the compiler cannot convert from `Node` to `T` it complains. Now, the `Node` has a member also called `front` which is `T` and I **suppose** that's what you want to return and that's what the fix does. (Possibly you want to return `front->node`. Your intent is not clear to me.)

In addition, you declared `temp` as `T const &` and `Front` returns it. However, the type returned by `Front` is `T&` (non `nonst`) and the compiler cannot convert from `const` to non-`const`. By declaring `temp` non-`const` (as in the fix) such conversion is no longer required.